# GAE Go runtime 1.11 needs more instances than runtime 1.9. It this common?

Tags: google-app-engine, go, google-cloud-platform

Since we migrated from go 1.9 to go 1.11 as Google required, we notice that GAE needs the double or triple amount of instances to handle the same traffic.

The code logic is pretty much the same because we don't have time to rewrite the application with Go 1.12 yet. We are still using `google.golang.org/appengine` instead of the new SDK.

I just want to know if others have a similar experience?

Comment: I don't have this comparison, but there are some minor differences between go 1.9 and go 1.11 as per https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/runtimes. Specifically go 1.11 has no restriction on network calls and allows read/write to /tmp. You may want to do some tracing to pinpoint any additional latency or if there is difference in memory/cpu usage before and after.

Comment: The interesting thing is based on the logs, the app in go runtime 1.11 seems running faster with lower latency. When I look at the instances UI in GCP, I can see quite some instances with not much workload. Well, that's kind of expected when you have many more instances than needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue seems to be related to a bug in Go runtime 1.9

> The Go 1.9 runtime has a known issue of ignoring the max_concurrent_requests setting. The Go 1.11 and newer runtimes respect the value of the max_concurrent_requests setting in your project's app.yaml file.

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go111/go-differences

That means when you have the same max_concurrent_requests in the yaml files for both versions, the outcome could be very different.

I am still trying to figure out what exactly it means by "ignore". Google support staff suggested that means Go runtime 1.9 always runs on 10 max_concurrent_requests. I have doubt on that conclusion at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

You can try for **Manual Scaling** if you think the number of instances are more than needed, try some tests and check the performance.